# How can I update a SQL database table using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need update database and the problem is: it is not possible to load an "id" or user that I wanna to update. If I choose an user according to "id", the application does not know find that user, no user. I do not know to correct this problem. Thank you for help.
PHP code:

```
       <?php 
       $id_user=$_GET['id'];

        $server_name="localhost";
        $db_user_name="root";
        $password="root";
        $db_name="prva";
        $connection=mysqli_connect($server_name, $db_user_name,$password,$db_name);

        if($connection) {
            echo 'Connected';}

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && $_GET['edit_user_form']){
            $user_name = $_GET['user_name'];
            $user_surname = $_GET['user_surname'];

            if(preg_match('#^.{0,50}$#', $user_name) &&
               preg_match('#^.{1,50}$#', $user_surname)){

            $sql_query = "UPDATE users SET user_name="; 
            if($user_name){
            $sql_query .= "'".$user_name."',";
            }else{
            $sql_query .= "NULL,";
            }

            $sql_query .= "user_surname='".$user_surname."'";


            $sql_query .= " WHERE id=".$id_user.";";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query);


                      if ($result) {
                          echo '<p class="success">Updated</p>';
                            }else{
                          echo '<p class="error">Error</p>';
                          }
                          // echo "Error: " . $sql_query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);

                }else{

                echo '<p class="error">Wrong data </p>';
                      }
              }

       if($id_user){
       $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$id_user.";";

       $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {    
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $user_name = $data[0]['user_name'];
            $user_surname = $data[0]['user_surname'];?>
```

The form looks:

```
    <form class="contact_form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="get">
        <label for="user_name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" value="<?php echo $user_name;?>">

        <label for="user_surname">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_surname" id="user_surname" value="<?php echo $user_surname;?>">

        <input type="submit" name="edit_user_form" value="Update">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="<?php echo $id_user;?>">
    </form>
```

And PHP code (the rest):

```
  <?php
    }else{
        echo '<p class="error">Data for editing are not loaded .</p>';
    }

      }else{
      echo '<p class="error">Parameter of user is not loaded .</p>';
    }?>
```

Comment: It sounds like you are adding a new user, not updating an existing one, hence there is no `id`.

Comment: I forgot to add the code -  $sql_query = "UPDATE users SET user_name="; 
  
above -  if($user_name){sql_query .= "'".$user_name."',";.... Still not working.

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query);


                      if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query)) {` you're querying twice here and theoretically, you should be getting a `1` as an error.

Comment: Yes you are right but when I corrected that, it is not working.

Comment: <s>Is this your full PHP code? Because I count more `{` than `}`. You should be getting syntax errors.</s> **Edit** Never mind, I miscounted.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **value** of your hidden field in HTML, it needs to be populated with the user id :

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id_user;?>">
```

Comment: I tried to correct that but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the wrong parameter from `$_GET`.
The name attribute of your input is `id_user`, but your taking `id`.

Do that instead:

```
$id_user = $_GET['id_user'];
```

You should also sanitize your input with [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php):

```
$id_user = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['id_user']);
```